# Table is overlapping text

Tags: tables

I'm using the IEEE format latex files from here:

http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/

I have the following code:

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\hline

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{UHF/VHF Antenna Specifications} \\

\hline

{\bf Model} & 2MCP22 \\
Frequency Range & 144-148 MHz \\
Gain @ 145.9 MHz & 12.25 dBdc \\
Front to back & 25 dB Typical \\
Beamwidth & 38° \\
Feed impedance & 50 Ohms Unbalanced \\
VSWR & 1.4: Max \\
Input Connector & ‘N’ Female \\
Power Handling & 1.5 KW \\
Stacking Distance & 9.5-10 ft \\
Boom length & 18’ 7” \\
Boom Diameter & 1-1/2”, Tapering to 1” \\
Elements/Type & 22 / 3/16” Aluminum Rod \\
Turning radius & 10 ft \\
Wind area & $2.5 ft^2$ \\
Weight / Ship Wt. & 12.5 lbs / 14 lbs UPS  \\
\hline
{\bf Model} & 436CP42 U/G \\
Frequency Range & 430-438 MHz \\
Gain & 16.8 dBdc \\
Beamwidth & 21° circular \\
Polarity & Circular, RHC or LHC \\
Front to Back & 25 dB Typical \\
Ellipticity & 1.5 dB Typical \\ 
VSWR & 1.5:1 and better \\
Feed impedance & 50W, Unbalanced \\
Connector & ‘N’ Female \\
Power handling & 1 kW \\
Stacking Distance & E=68” H=68” \\
Turning radius & 95° \\
Wind Area & $2 ft^2$ \\ 
Mast Size & 1-1/2 to 2 Inches \\ 
Weight / Ship Wt. & 7.8 lbs / 10 lbs UPS \\
\hline
{\bf Model} & 2.4-15R \\
Frequency Range & 2.4-2.5 GHz \\
Gain & 15 dBi \\
Front to Back & 16 dB \\
VSWR & 1.5:1 Max \\
Polarity & Vertical / Horizontal \\
Feed Impedance & 50 Ohms \\
Feed Connector & ‘N’ Female \\
Power Handling & 500 W \\
Boom Length & 25” \\
Radome Diameter & 3.3” \\
Mast Size & 1-1/4 to 2 Inches \\
Wind Area & 1 $ft^2$ \\     
Wind Rating & 100 mph \\      
Weight & 1 lb \\

\hline

\end{tabular} \\

\end{center}
```

For some reason the table is overlapping the text directly after it, I've posted a picture here:
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxtHMBPFxja0OTU4MTViNzItMjQ4ZS00MTgwLWE5OTktMWY3NGJkZjU1ZDQy&hl=en&authkey=CN_7j70D

I've tried wrapping it in a

```
\begin{table}

...table here...

\end{table}
```

but I get errors doing that

This is going to drive me crazy, trying \\ or \newpage or something to get it on it's own isn't helping.

EDIT: Clarified overlapping problem.

EDIT2: Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass[final]{ieee}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  {\bf Model} & 2.4-15R \\
  Frequency Range & 2.4-2.5 GHz \\
  Gain & 15 dBi \\
  Front to Back & 16 dB \\
  VSWR & 1.5:1 Max \\
  Polarity & Vertical / Horizontal \\
  Feed Impedance & 50 Ohms \\
  Feed Connector & ‘N’ Female \\
  Power Handling & 500 W \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \\

\end{center}
\PARstart The GENSO network will consist of a MCC, GSS and AUS. Each satellite communicates with an individual MCC which acts as a server. All data and voice transmissions for the given satellite are downloaded by different GSS's throughout the world and routed to the correct MCC where it is retained for later dissemination. [...]

\end{document}
```

The other `ieee` class is from the site I linked initially at the top.

Comment: I'm surprised this code compiles, how come it doesn't complain about the `@`?

Comment: does the longtable package help? http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=longtable

Comment: @Seamus. Why should it complain because of a @? That's a normal character which you can use like "a" or "!". (You can't use it in a command, but that's another question).

Comment: Nothing in the tabular explains the overlapping. So the problem lies elsewhere. Make a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What about all that `\makeatletter` shenanigans I see occasionally?

Comment: @Seamus: `\makeatletter` makes `@` a letter, so you can use it as part of a macro name.  Otherwise, `@`'s just a character like `,`, `!`, or `.`.  (This is what `\makeatother` does, as well as the default state.)  You can't use them in macro names (unless they're the *only* character), but they typeset just fine.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I can post the entire file if you'd like, but it's 9 pages, so it's up to you whether you really wish to wade through that, I can't think of another way to make a complete example.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the tabular definition. (It works fine with the `ieeetrans` class which is similar to ieee with your full example). I would try and use the `longtable` package as suggested above. Alternative stop compilation at various strategic places by using `\end{document}` to see where the error lies. It can be in the class itself.

Comment: Ulrike requested a *minimal* example. I shortend your file to contain only enough material to exhibit the problem.

Comment: There seems to be a strange interaction between `center` and `\PARstart`. If I remove one of them, the problem goes away.

Comment: The longtable solution is suboptimal, since longtable doesn't like multicolumn environments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the `ieee` class. Adding an empty box after the `center` environment solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[final]{ieee}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  {\bf Model} & 2.4-15R \\
  Frequency Range & 2.4-2.5 GHz \\
  Gain & 15 dBi \\
  Front to Back & 16 dB \\
  VSWR & 1.5:1 Max \\
  Polarity & Vertical / Horizontal \\
  Feed Impedance & 50 Ohms \\
  Feed Connector & ‘N’ Female \\
  Power Handling & 500 W \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}\mbox{} %note the \mbox here

\PARstart The GENSO network will consist of a MCC, GSS and AUS. Each satellite communicates with an individual MCC which acts as a server. All data and voice transmissions for the given satellite are downloaded by different GSS's throughout the world and routed to the correct MCC where it is retained for later dissemination. [...]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another solution is to use the `[b]` optional argument for `{tabular}`: `\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}`.

Comment: If this is really a bug I suggest that the OP submits a bug report...though I couldn't find where one would submit it to....

Comment: Aside from submitting my entire paper, which I suppose I could, I'm not sure how to describe the exact "problem" and it's solution, it looks like the mbox works, but does anyone have a suggestion as to why?

Comment: \PARstart sets \lineskiplimit to -1000pt. This means that objects (like your tabular and the large T at the start of the paragraph) with a large height or a large depth will no longer push lines apart. There are better ways to code such large chars at the start of a paragraph (see e.g. lettrine). The \mbox works as it is a small empty line.