# squeeze the text in table

Tags: tables, longtable, hyphenation

I had gone thro this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6904/10008) and still in my case, i have the overlapping text in the table

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    % to change certain pages to landscape mode
\usepackage{longtable}  % for tables spanning multiple pages
\begin{document}

This is my example


\begin{landscape}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline 
ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH  & H & H & H & H & OCH2-CH=C(CH3)CH2CH2CH=C(CH3)2 & H  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\newline
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I can not expand / compress the column size.

The question is how to fix the overflowing text in 6th column. Whereas column 1 fits properly.

Should i manually hyphenate the text to fit into the desired cell width?

Comment: I think that the problem is related to the hyphenation. As TeX doesn't know how to split that long string. If you hyphenate it, then it doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

This version switches category codes, so can not be used in the argument to another command, but works OK here I think. The penalty0 *allows* breaks at those points, if some are more desirable than others you could give the desirable ones negative penalties and the undesirable ones positive penalties.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    % to change certain pages to landscape mode
\usepackage{longtable}  % for tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}\mybreaks}p{#1}}

\begingroup
\catcode`=\active
\catcode`-\active
\catcode`)\active
\gdef\mybreaks{%
\catcode`=\active\edef={\string=\penalty0 }%
\catcode`)\active\edef){\string)\penalty0 }%
\catcode`-\active\edef-{\string-\penalty0 }}
\endgroup
\begin{document}

This is my example


\begin{landscape}
 \begin{tabular}{|P{5cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|P{2cm}|}
\hline 
ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH ABCD EFGH  ABCD EFGH  & H & H & H & H & OCH2-CH=C(CH3)CH2CH2CH=C(CH3)2 & H  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\newline
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```